# ¿Hacer dos veces mi programa para tener una versión de 32 y otra de 64 bits?

Tags: python

Estoy realizando mis primeros programas y en medio de todo esto me ha surgido la duda, uso un sistema de 64bts pero ¿si quiero correr mi programa en un sistema de 32 bits, tendré que programarlo en un sistema de 32 bits? O ¿habrá alguna forma de usar mi programa de 64 y pasarlo a 32 sin tener que programar todo de nuevo?
Posdsta: estoy programando en python

Comment: Python es un lenguaje interpretado y corre dentro de una máquina virtual que lo aisla del hardware en que corre. Un mismo programa Python correra en cualquier CPU (Intel, AMD, ARM, ...) y sistema operativo (Linux, Windows, Mac, Unix, ...). En resumen, no importa si es 32bits o 64bits.

Comment: Incluso puedes meter instrucciones especificas para 32 y/o 64 bits en un mismo código, previamente identificando el sistema, por ejemplo el módulo platform: `platform.machine()` produce salidas como `x86`, `AMD64`, `x86_64`, dependiendo del OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bienvenido Davi Mende, espero que esto te ayude:

No encontrarás diferencias en cuanto al código de los programas en sí. Los tipos de datos de Python (versión 3) no dependen del ancho de palabra de la máquina donde se ejecutan. Es el usuario quien elige la versión del interprete, ya sea 32 o 64 bits a la hora de instalarlo en su ordenador.

Donde sí encontrarás diferencias es en capacidad y rendimiento. El Python es un lenguaje interpretado, y por lo tanto se ejecuta sobre un interprete, el cual lee cada instrucción del programa y lo convierte a código que se ejecuta secuencialmente.